# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.BellasHBG.LocationService cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.BellasHBG.LocationService cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`
but I don't know how to resolve.  Removing keyword abstract does not fix the problem.  This is new to me, and I'm not that knowledgeable of java so any help is appreciated.  The error seems top be occurring in LocationService on the following line: `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mlocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);`

The intent is to get location updates and send a notification to the app user if the location sells this particular bakery product.

Below are my MainActivity, LocationService and AndroidManifest.xml

MainActivity

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView = null;
    public static boolean orignotifsetting = false;


    //PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private Alarm alarm;
    MyToolBox mtools = new MyToolBox();
    LocationIntentService mLocationIntentService = new LocationIntentService();
    public LocationManager mlocManager;
    //LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    //LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;
    public Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    LocationServiceImpl mLocationService = new LocationServiceImpl();
    public static boolean prevNotificationsSetting;





    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("myTag", "in onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //set the default values first time run but don't overwrite them if they have been set
        //  ----------------------------------------------------------------| - true will leave them alone, false will clear them every time
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.pref_notification, true);

        this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //myWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
       //myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new WebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.bellashbg.com");
        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.i("myTag", "in onResume");
        super.onResume();

        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationService.class);
        if ((mtools.notificationsSetting(this)) & (prevNotificationsSetting == false)) {
            prevNotificationsSetting = true;
            startService(msgIntent);

        }
        else {
            if ((!mtools.notificationsSetting(this)) & (prevNotificationsSetting == true)) {

                //   mLocationService.stopLocationUpdates();
                prevNotificationsSetting = false;
                boolean result = stopService(msgIntent);
                if (result){
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "stopService true");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "stopService false");
                }

                //mLocationService.stopLocationUpdates();
                //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i("myTag", "in onPause");
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override

    public void onStop() {
        Log.i("myTag", "in onStop");
        super.onStop();

    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("myTag", "in onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        //if (mSensorManager!=null){mSensorManager.unregisterListener(listener);}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.i("myTag", "in onCreateOptionsMenu");
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);  // cmnted 10/25/2015
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        //return true;
        // return true;  stack overflow 6439085 says to return true to pop up menu
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("myTag", "in onOptionsItemSelected");
        //LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  //added 11/12/2015 to remove updates
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:
                Intent settingsintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(settingsintent);

                break;
            case R.id.help:
                break;
            case R.id.about:
                break;
        }
        return true;

    }
    // Get the notifications status bar setting
    public boolean notificationsSettingNotificationBar() {
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean notificationsNewMessageNotificationBar = SP.getBoolean("notifications_new_message_notification_bar", true);
        return notificationsNewMessageNotificationBar;
    }


    // Get the notifications ringtone
    public String notificationsSettingRingtone() {
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String notificationsNewMessageRingtone = SP.getString("notifications_new_message_ringtone", "NULL");
        return notificationsNewMessageRingtone;
    }

    // Get the notifications vibrate setting
    public boolean notificationsNewMessageSetting() {
        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean notificationNewMessageVibrate = SP.getBoolean("notifications_new_message_vibrate", true);
        return notificationNewMessageVibrate;
    }

    private TextView latituteField;
    private Context mContext;

}
```

LocationService

```
package com.example.BellasHBG;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
//import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;


//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
//import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
//import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
//import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
//import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
//import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
//import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
//import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

/**
 * Created by craigmartensen on 4/7/16.
 */
public abstract class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 60000 * 1;  // 1000 milliseconds in 1 second
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 5;
    public static final long LOCATION_DISTANCE_IN_METERS = 3;
    MyToolBox mtools = new MyToolBox();
    public static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    //public static GoogleSignInClient mSignInClient;
    public static GoogleSignInAccount mSignInClient;
    LocationRequest mlocationRequest;
    private boolean isRemoving = false;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        isRemoving = false;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }




    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        //alarm.SetAlarm(this);
        //return START_STICKY;

        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        //Toast.makeText(this, "onHandleIntent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //mGoogleApiClient.connect();


        Log.d("onStartCommand", "Service Started");

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        if (isRemoving) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
         else {
            isRemoving = false;
            mlocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mlocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
            mlocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
            mlocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mlocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(LOCATION_DISTANCE_IN_METERS);

            Intent locationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationIntentService.class);
            locationIntent.putExtra("ID", "FusedLcation");
            PendingIntent locationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, locationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mlocationRequest, locationPendingIntent);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mlocationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
        }


    }



    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Entering method");
        //Toast.makeText(this, "onLocationChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();


        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "entering onLocationChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String myText;

        double mlat = loc.getLatitude();

        double mlong = loc.getLongitude();


        DBHelper myDBHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        // use the following line if you just want to know if the location is found ie, sells Bellas
        //boolean soldHere = myDBHelper.doesLocationSellBellas("my_table",41.685471,-73.975393);
        // the following line retrieves the name of the location that sells bellas, null if it's not found
        //String locName = myDBHelper.getLocationName("my_table", 41.685471, -73.975393);
        String locName = myDBHelper.getLocationName(DBHelper.LOCATION_TABLE_NAME, mlat, mlong);

        // set up for notification in the notification status bar

        if (locName != null) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("Bella's sold here");
                // .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Bella's sold here"));
                //                      .setSubText(todaysjolt);
                //   .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                //.setContentText("Bella's sold here");
                // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
                NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                // Builds the notification and issues it.


                mBuilder.setContentText(locName);
                mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(locName));

                // new 10/14/2015 - set up to allow user to go to website from notification

                // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

                // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
                // started Activity.
                // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
                // your application to the Home screen.
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                0,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        );
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

                // end new 10/14/2015


                mNotifyMgr.notify(000, mBuilder.build());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are at " + locName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (mtools.notificationsSetting(this)) {
            MainActivity.orignotifsetting = true;
            //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates() {

        if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            isRemoving = true; //added
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        else {

        //if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {


        //    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {


                PendingIntent locationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, LocationIntentService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationPendingIntent);  //moved below 1/28/2016
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) com.example.BellasHBG.LocationService.this);
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
                stopSelf();  // stop the service
            }
        //}
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d("LocationUpdateService", "Connection Suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        stopLocationUpdates();
        //reportarGPS.interrupt();
        //reportarGPS = null;
        //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
        //mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

        //mGoogleApiClient = null;
        //mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.BellasHBG">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/bellas_logo_48x36"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BellasHBG"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">



        <activity

            android:name="com.example.BellasHBG.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/action_settings"/>


        <activity

            android:name="com.example.BellasHBG.CreateNotificationOnBar"
            android:label="create_notification_on_bar"/>

        <activity

            android:name="com.example.BellasHBG.CustomPreference"
            android:label="custom_preference"/>



        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Bella's Home Baked Goods" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>




        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.BellasHBG.Alarm" />
        <service android:enabled='true' android:name="com.example.BellasHBG.LocationService" />



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please uncomment the import for com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener on LocationService and give a try again.

Comment: I tried that but application stops in emulator and I logcat doesn't have any information in it.

Comment: Latest error message:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.BellasHBG.LocationService: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.BellasHBG.LocationService cannot be instantiated`

Comment: I removed 'abstract' from the class definition and along with using the import for com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener and now it seems to be working.  Thank you.